# Improve speed of write/send vibration data for a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, fft, fftw, vibration

I would like some comments for speeding up writing and sending data for my vibration measurement system.

I have a system of 10 Raspberry Pi's (both rpi 3b+ and rpi 4), each with a triaxial accelerometer which acquires 3200 samples/second in each x,y,z-axis. Each minute a new CVS file is generated on each rpi, and recordings for the next minute is appended to this file, closed and send via ftp to a laptop where all data are gathered and post-processed.

Data within the CSV files are integers and integers only. No headers or similar. Filenames consist of a sensor number and an epoch timestamp, so all filenames are unique.

Should I change format, e.g. HDF5 (why - seems only to be good for larger data tables), or Panda PyTables, feather-format (appears only to utilize binear data - should I consider converting data?), Pickle, UFF58, ...?

Should I consider another approach instead of generating a new CSV file every minute, maybe not append but keep data in memory until they are needed for writing to a CSV file? (I need the data send to my laptop every minute). If so, how can this be done?

Other considerations as to improve I/O performance?

Comment: What do you mean by *"speed up"*? Do you mean you want to take more readings per second? Or you want to get the readings to the laptop with less than a minute's latency? Are you using WiFi or wired? What's the actual issue? Are you saturating network bsndwidth? Have you tested to see if your data is compressible? Have you tried binary files rather than ASCII?

Comment: slow can be caused by maxing out of CPU or network or filesystem IO or ...  you need to measure to identify which of these resources is causing the slowness ... did you try chunking up the writes to file so measure for X samples then append to file instead of doing an entire minute of writes all at once ... is your acquire in its own thread ? and the file IO in its own thread ?